# $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\sin(y)}{x} $

Tags: calculus

Who is  $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(y)}{x} $ ?

I was thinking that since $x=y$, the above limit is equivalent to $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1. $ But I'am not so sure.

Comment: Let $y=kx$, then the limit is different for different $k$.

Comment: It is possible that $x=y$ approaching the the limit, but anything else is also possible.  For example $x=y^2$ and $x=\sqrt{x}$ are other possibilities which produce different limits

Comment: Easy to see with the choice $(x_n, y_n) = (1/n, 0)$ that the limit is not $1$.

Comment: Okay. Right. Thank you. Do you have any hints in order to find the right solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=kx$, so the limit becomes:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\sin(y)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(kx)}{x}=k\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(kx)}{kx}=k\cdot1=k $$

Since the limit depends on $k$ and $k$ is arbitrary real number, hence the limit doesn't exsit.